# vue.js, setTimeout interfere with my simple countdown

Tags: vue.js, settimeout, cleartimeout

i have simplified my code to clarify the problem, this vue page shows a question for ten seconds and the student should say the answer before it shows up, but here is the problem, i have a next button which shows the next question, consider 5 seconds left and you press the next button then countdown completely tears apart, even it shows minus digits!

```
<template>
  <div class="container text-center">
      <div v-if = "showQuestion">
     <span> {{ question }} </span>
      <span style="color:red;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ countDown }} </span>

    </div>

    <div v-if = "showAnswer">
            <p> {{ answer }} </p>
    </div>

    <div>
       <button class="btn btn-success" @click="next">next question </button>
         
    </div>
     
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
     data(){
        return{
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4', 'question5'] ,   
            answers: ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'answer4', 'answer5'],
           
            question: '',
            answer: '',
           mayVar: null, //controlls setTimeout
            index : 0, 
             showQuestion: true,
             showAnswer: false,
              countDown : 10,           
            
        }
    },
    methods:{
        
            startQuiz(){
               this.countDown = 10;
               this.question = this.questions[this.index];
               this.answer = this.answers[this.index];
               this.countDownTimer();
               this.show();
              
            },

            show(){                
                 this.myVar =  setTimeout(() => { //question fades away and answer shows up
                       this.showQuestion = false;
                       this.showAnswer = true;

                    }, 10000);
            },

             next(){
                  clearTimeout(this.myVar); // 
                 this.index++;// goes to next question
                   this.showQuestion = true;
                 this.showAnswer = false;
                this.startQuiz();
                
             },
                 
             countDownTimer() {
                  
                if(this.countDown > 0) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.countDown--;
                        this.countDownTimer();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
    },

    created(){
      this.startQuiz();
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

thank you

here is the link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raminSafari/b7zhc98q/)

Comment: when you press next make set `countDown`  to 10sec

Comment: thanks @CodeBug i just tried, doesn't work

Comment: It would be fine if you add online playground example for your code - [Online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xtfzwcu8/)

Comment: thanks @Muhammad i just added the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear the countdown timer also, when you press next. See the below snippet.

```js
const app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data(){
        return{
            questions: ['question1', 'question2', 'question3', 'question4', 'question5'] ,   
            answers: ['answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3', 'answer4', 'answer5'],
           
            question: '',
            answer: '',
           mayVar: null, //controlls setTimeout
            index : 0, 
             showQuestion: true,
             showAnswer: false,
              countDown : 10,   
              count_down_timer: null // controls count down timer
            
        }
    },
    methods:{
        
            startQuiz(){
               this.countDown = 10;
               this.question = this.questions[this.index];
               this.answer = this.answers[this.index];
               this.countDownTimer();
               this.show();
              
            },

            show(){                
                 this.myVar =  setTimeout(() => { //question fades away and answer shows up
                       this.showQuestion = false;
                       this.showAnswer = true;

                    }, 10000);
            },

             next(){
                  clearTimeout(this.myVar); // 
                  clearTimeout(this.count_down_timer)
                 this.index++;// goes to next question
                   this.showQuestion = true;
                 this.showAnswer = false;
                this.startQuiz();
                
             },
                 
             countDownTimer() {
                  
                if(this.countDown > 0) {
                    this.count_down_timer = setTimeout(() => {
                        this.countDown--;
                        this.countDownTimer();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },
    },

    created(){
      this.startQuiz();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="container text-center">
      <div v-if = "showQuestion">
     <span> {{ question }} </span>
      <span style="color:red;"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ countDown }} </span>

    </div>

    <div v-if = "showAnswer">
            <p> {{ answer }} </p>
    </div>

    <div>
       <button class="btn btn-success" @click="next">next question </button>
         
    </div>
     
  </div>
</div>
```